# How to get cursor to flash when asking user for input in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and asking user for input:

```py
name = input("Please state your name   ")
```

I want the user to see the cursor so they know where the typing is going to happen. I use two spaces after name so they have room between the message and what they type, but would like to have a flashing cursor like this:

```
Please state your name  __
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's up to the displaying program (e.g. IDLE, Pycharm, console etc.). For example, waiting for input in Pycharm I have a flashing `|` where the input goes...

Comment: I am using pycharm with python 3.7 and i get nothing after the request for input from user

Comment: Click once on the run window...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult an [ANSI vt100](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) reference, and look for "blinking".

It's not hard to display blinking characters,
and then erase them after input is received.
Here are some characters you might choose to use:

```
>>> esc = chr(27)
>>> print(f'a{esc}[5m_\u2592b\u2588{esc}[m_c')
a_▒b█_c
```